# php preg_replace regex to replace function type string with its parameters

Tags: php, regex

I've text for example.

```
a quick brown fox sance("jumps") over a lazy ok("good") dog.
```

I want to remove sance() from the above string but inside text. so the output will look like

`a quick brown fox "jumps" over a lazy ok("good") dog.`

i tried too many regex to remove only sance() but have no luck. most of the time it replaces other ok("good") which is not acceptable.

can somebody plz help me?

Comment: Please come up with what you have done so far. Currently you are just asking for someone others solution without even proving that you know what you are talking about.

Comment: Can there be nested function calls like: `a quick brown fox sance("jumps" + strtolower("FOO") + "123" ) over a lazy ok("good") dog.`

Comment: i tried to many regex to achieve my specific output in function preg_replace('REGEX', '$1', INPUT) but with no luck. However, @Bora's regex worked.

Comment: @anubhava, no, in my case its not nested function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$string = 'a quick brown fox sance("jumps") over a lazy ok("good") dog.';

echo preg_replace('/sance\((.*?)\)/', '$1', $string);
```

#### Output

```
a quick brown fox "jumps" over a lazy ok("good") dog.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/sance\((\S+)\)/";
$replace = "\1";
$input_lines = 'a quick brown fox sance("jumps") over a lazy ok("good") dog.';

preg_replace($pattern, $replace , $input_lines);
```

try it